# C++ Binary Search Tree Insert Implementation

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to build a function to insert into a binary search tree, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why it won't work. I understand fundamentally how the function is supposed to work, but based on the template I was given it seems as though I am to avoid creating a BST class but instead rely on the Node class and build the desired functions to work on that. Here's the given template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Node {
    int value;
public:
    Node* left;       // left child
    Node* right;      // right child
    Node* p;          // parent
    Node(int data) {
        value = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        p  = NULL;
    }
    ~Node() {
    }
    int d() {
        return value;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};

function insert(Node *insert_node, Node *tree_root){
    //Your code here
}
```

The issue I'm having is when I implement the following code, where getValue is a simple getter method for Node:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     Node* root = NULL;
     Node* a = new Node(2);
     insert(a, root);
}

void insert(Node *insert_node, Node *tree_root){
    if (tree_root == NULL)      
        tree_root = new Node(insert_node->getValue());
```

The code appears to compile and run without error, but if I run another check on root after this, it returns NULL. Any idea what I'm missing here? Why is it not replacing root with a new node equal to that of insert_node?

I also realize this doesn't appear to be the optimal way to implement a BST, but I am trying to work with the template given to me. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for and read about *passing arguments by reference in c++*.

Comment: `void insert(Node *insert_node, Node*& tree_root)`.

Comment: Even better `void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> insert_node, std::unique_ptr<Node>& tree_root)`.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for the input! What makes that second version even better?

Comment: Smart pointers allow to not manually handle memory. So you would have no memory leak in your example with `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim said your issue relates to difference between passing parameter by reference and by value.

In your code `void insert(Node *insert_node, Node *tree_root)` you pass `Node* tree_root` by value. Inside the function you change local copy of this pointer, so outer value is not changed.

To fix it you should pass `Node* tree_root` by [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/). Parameter declaration can be `Node*& tree_root` (or `Node** tree_root`). E.g:

```
void insert(Node* insert_node, Node*& tree_root){
    if (tree_root == NULL)      
        tree_root = new Node(insert_node->getValue());
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this was an excellent explanation for this. I am still trying to totally wrap my head around the most appropriate times to pass arguments for reference, and certainly have more reading to do, but this explanation helped greatly.